# how restrict values of chosen weights in matlab neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

everyone!
I know about regularization, but I wanna restrict only choosen weights. For example, I have code

```
H = rand(10, 100);
H = rand(1,  100);
net = newff(H, F, [10, 5], { 'tansig' 'tansig'}, 'traingdx', 'learngdm', 'mse');
net = train(net, H, F);
```

and i wanna have during train

```
net.IW{1}(i, i) = 0
```

or even

```
a <= net.IW{1}(i - 1 : i + 1, i) <= b
```

how can i achieve this result?

Comment: You can't do that with the neural network toolbox.  You must write your own optimization procedure that will specifically set the contribution of the gradient update as well as the contribution to the cost function where those weights are specifically forced to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any example of such codes on github etc.? I tried to override tansig (just add string fprintf('tansig')), but when I write tansig(1) from matlab, i get overriden tansig, and this tansig isn't overriden when using in activation function. Why?